# Not using Github anymore - Sourcetree keeps asking for password

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I've moved my repositories from Github (where they were created) to Bitbucket and have been working happy for a while. Every now and then Source Tree asks for my Github password.

My Local Repositories pages doesn't have any repos that are on Github.

My Remote Repositories doesn't have any repos on it.

My Tools>Options>Authentications page doesn't have any Github accounts.

Are there other places I need to remove my Github account from?
What might be causing this?
Why is it asking?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue- I migrated a repository from GitHub to Bitbucket, and then removed the account from Tools>Options>Authentication. I then started getting a periodic prompt for my GitHub account.

I still had the GitHub repo bookmarked in SourceTree, and once I removed the bookmark the prompts stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running windows? If so you might want to uninstall your git-credential-manager and check to see if your windows credential manager has an entry for github. If so delete that too.

Comment: I still have a github account and want to be able to log into it. I just want Sourcetree to stop promoting me for the password because the app shouldn't need it.